# Mi fragment no detecta findViewBiId

Tags: android, android-fragment

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en donde tengo que incorporar un Recyclerview dentro de un navigation drawer, pero al momento de querer poner findViewBiId dentro del fragmento del navigation drawer no me lo reconoce

```
RecyclerView myrv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle_artista);
    AdapterArtista myAdapter = new AdapterArtista(this, lstArtista);
    myrv.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
    myrv.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

y el inicio de mi fragment es el siguiente

```
public class ArtistaFragmento extends Fragment {

List <Artista> lstArtista;

public ArtistaFragmento(){

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

Comment: ¿Mayra, te sirvió la respuesta?.  Si es así, por favor, márcala como aceptada.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

En el OnCreateView deberías "inflar" la vista y luego, con la vista creada, podrás buscar tu vista.
Por ejemplo:

```
View rootView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.miVista, null);
RecyclerView myrv = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycle_artista);
```

Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

> Para un funcionamiento más optimo, te recomiendo utilizar la vinculación de vista **"View Binding"**
>
> Agrega esta línea en tu build.gradle (app) y dale en **"sync now"**

```
viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
```

> Después vincula tu Fragment

```
    private ArtistaFragmentobinding binding;
```

> En tu método onCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater,
                          ViewGroup container,
                          Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    binding = ArtistaFragmentobinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}
```

> Dentro de tu método onViewCreated, mandas a  llamar cualquier componente que exista en tu vista, y te olvidas por completo del findViewById()

```
binding.recycle_artista
```

Espero que te sirva esta explicación, es mucho más práctico, obtener referencias de vista, sin necesidad de estarlas declarando en la clasey optimizas la memoria

Saludos